# Face recognition terminal iVMS-4200 does not connect to the base

Tags: mysql, terminal, face-recognition, hikvision

Face recognition terminal iVMS-4200 shows an error when connecting to the mysql database. I tried like the following video on Youtube. But it's showing error while saving. Please help. I am attaching a picture.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoQy2yejzBI

I tried like this youtube video but I get the error like in the picture

Comment: I installed a virtual server "MAMP". It has MySQL version 5.7. I tried connecting to this server in Python. The connection was successful. But there is always an error in the iVMS program.

Comment: `import mysql.connector`
`db = mysql.connector.connect(`
    `host = "localhost",`
    `user = "root",`
    `passwd = "root",`
    `database = "imron"`
`)`
`mycursor = db.cursor()`

`mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nik")`

`myresult = mycursor.fetchall()`
`print(len(myresult))`  *return 0*

Comment: I notice you are using the local loopback address in iVMS, but localhost in your python connection. Did you try localhost in iVMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Mysql 5.0.45. it will work.

Comment: We are using this with ivms 4200 V3.8.0.4 and it is working fine